# How can you stop terminal from showing the running threads when quitting it using Applescript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

So I want to force quit some applications. The method described on [this Macscripter thread](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=15240) describes a way which works for most applications.

```
tell application "SomeApp" to quit saving no
```

However, when used on Terminal when it is running some process, it, it gives me this pop-up:

[image: image of terminal complaining]

I want to get this pop-up when using the terminal manually but not when "force quitting" it. Is there a way around this without disabling the function entirely and without UI Scripting.

Comment: How about using: `do shell script "pkill -9 'Terminal'"`

Comment: @user3439894 The `pkill` command doesn't provide any output and also doesn't quit the Terminal.

Comment: `killall Terminal` should do it

Comment: It does quit **Terminal** and what _output_ do you want as you didn't ask for any in the question that I saw.

Comment: @user3439894 I mean output as in error output. And no, I copied your exact command and it didn't quit the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but is there a way to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: You can use `do shell script "pkill -xi terminal"` as `-x` forces an exact match on the _process name_ and `-i` ignores _case_. -- `killall` is _case sensitive_.

Comment: Still doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Comment: It works for me and I wouldn't have posted it otherwise.